# What is the residual, seasonal component in time-series decomposition represents?

Tags: time-series, python, residuals, seasonality, trend

I am doing time series analysis on the below dataset-
[Here's link](https://www.kaggle.com/dougcresswell/daily-total-female-births-in-california-1959)

This is what I got on the decomposition of the dataset in python-
[image]

Well, I know the meaning of every word i.e-
The trend represents an increasing, decreasing trend in the dataset.
Seasonality represents the repetition of a specific pattern in a seasonal manner (after some time periods).
The residual represents the remainder component.
But I am unable to relate these meaning with respect to the above graphs.

Comment: At each day the value of your time series (Original) is the sum of its trend, its seasonal component and (by definition) the residuals. In formualic terms: $O_t = T_t + S_t + R_t$ where $O_t$ is the original series at time $t$, $T_t$ is the trend and so on.

Comment: Is these components effects on choosing the time-series model for fitting.